# Are these tiny white dots on my bread mold?

Tags: bread, mold

I've never seen mold look like this before. I've also never noticed these on my bread in the past. I Just bought this loaf of white bread two days ago so it should still be good although I can't find a use by date on the bag. I bit into a piece of bread last week that had very obvious (but I was exhausted) mold in it. Am I just being overly cautious now?[image][image][image]

Answer (score 5):

No it is not mold. They are coarse particles of some kind of grain (often corn meal, but in this case maybe wheat as corn meal is usually yellower). They sometimes sprinkle these on when they bake the bread; Sometimes on the bottom of the loaf (often with French bread) I think to keep the bread from sticking to the pan as it bakes. Also makes the bread look rustic and more "homemade."